# how to write multi-line functions in cider repl?

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

I'm using Clojure in Emacs with a Cider REPL.

Is it possible to have multi-line functions in a cider REPL? How can I do this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

<kbd>C-j</kbd> should do it. As a bonus you get indentation.

Comment: You're welcome. [Cider's keyboard shortcuts reference](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider#keyboard-shortcuts) is worth casting a look at, by the way.

Comment: The Cider documentation has moved [here](https://cider.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)